# Telerik RadDropDownList loses focus when searching an item by pressing a key that is a label shortcut

Tags: vb.net, telerik

I have many controls in a panel. One is a System.Windows.Forms.**Label** next to a text box, and another control is a Telerik.WinControls.UI.**RadDropDownList**.

The dropdown list has two items: True and False.
The label has a Text value of "%Type" (so a shortcut there).

When the dropdown list is focused and you press F, the False item gets selected, which is good. But if you press T, without the ALT key down, the focus jumps because of the label shortcut and the text box gets the focus.

Has anyone experienced this behavior or have any idea on how to work around this?

I noticed that the KeyDown event of the dropdown list is being triggered when pressing T but not the KeyUp or KeyPress event. Also, as soon as I remove the & from the label text, everything works fine.

Thanks!